# Reading OPC properties

Tags: opc

I'd like to sample properties of opc tags in my opc client.
What I don't understand is at what level are the tag's properties defined.
Can I assume that the properties are defined at the server level and all the tags have the same properties?
Or that they are defined at the tag's level and each tag can have its own properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your question is about OPC Data Access (v2.0 or v3.0), then there is no requirement for the sets of properties be the same on each item, and there is no "server-level" list of properties that would apply to all items.

This is expressed in the OPC specs, and also implied by how the corresponding interfaces and functions are defined: IOPCItemProperties::QueryAvailableProperties in OPC-DA 2.05a, and similarly, IOPCBrowse:: Browse in OPC-DA 3.0. These functions take an OPC Item ID as an input, and based on that can provide different sets of properties.

Of course, a specific OPC server may choose to provide the same set of properties on each item; but an OPC client that wants to be able to work with any OPC server cannot make such assumption.